# Python max() function doesnt give correct results when two strings are compared

Tags: python, max

I am new to Python. The task in hand is to find the latest build in a list of builds in a particular directory.

My code looks like this:

```
    command = 'ls ' + self.build_path
    stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(command)
    builds_list = stdout.read()

    arrBuild = builds_list.split('\n')
    joined = "|".join(arrBuild)
    self.latest_packages['relayws'] = max(re.findall("mybuild-relayws_[0-9]+.[0-9].[0-9]+-[0-9]_amd64.deb", joined))
```

Now my problem here is that, "mybuild-relayws_44.0.99-1_amd64.deb" is always considered latest when I have "mybuild-relayws_44.0.101-1_amd64.deb" in the list.

That is :

`max(['mybuild-relayws_44.0.99-1_amd64.deb', 'mybuild-relayws_44.0.101-1_amd64.deb'])` always returns `mybuild-relayws_44.0.99-1_amd64.deb.`

I understand that max() is using string comparison here and in that sense its returning it correct. However, in my case, I am expecting mybuild-relayws_44.0.101-1_amd64.deb

My questions are:

1. How can I change the max() function in the above code, that would return mybuild-relayws_44.0.101-1_amd64.deb as result
2. Is key=lambda in max function useful here? If yes, how to apply that to this code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Giving `max` the keyfunction is the correct approach - but in order to write a concrete keyfunction, we need concrete rules on how strings should be ordered.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I have edited my question above. Can you comment based on the edited question please?

Comment: I suspect python compares the strings character by character starting at position 0. At some point it hits the first "9" in "mybuild-relayws_44.0.99-1_amd64.deb" which is higher than the first "1" in mybuild-relayws_44.0.101-1_amd64.deb. You could split by underscore and grab the middle element to get the numbers only. Then split by full stop and hyphen and cast to int so python "realizes" that it's actually looking at the numbers 99 and 101 and not 9 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the version from `relayws`:

```
def version(relayws):
    return map(int, relayws.split('_')[1].replace('-', '.').split('.'))
```

then you can find the max by the key:

```
latest = max(builds, key=version)
```

Comment: You're welcome. I think @donkopotamus answer better explains it though.

Comment: @donkopotamus We posted at the exact same second (c:

Answer (score 3):

You have not given any rules about how you expect builds to be ordered.  Let me assume that you wish to order them based on the following:

- `firebet-relayws_44.0.99-1_amd64.deb` => `44.0.99-1`
- then `44.0.99-1` => a sequence of numbers `(44, 0, 99, 1)`
- we order based on that sequence.

Then try something like:

```
def get_version(txt):
   # extract eg 44.0.99-1
   version_data = txt.split("_")[1]

   # split into 44.0.99 and 1
   version, release = version_data.split("-")

   # convert them to a list of numbers
   return [int(x) for x in version.split(".")] + [int(release)]
```

Then, for example:

```
>>> print(get_version("firebet-relayws_44.0.99-1_amd64.deb"))
[44, 0, 99, 1]
```

Now we pass this as the key function to `max`

```
>>> print(max(['mybuild-relayws_44.0.99-1_amd64.deb', 'mybuild-relayws_44.0.101-1_amd64.deb'], key=get_version))
mybuild-relayws_44.0.101-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @donkopotamus, I tried both of the solutions and found equally awesome! Thanks